# Various way to colour auto-filtered cells in table column red

Tags: excel, vba

Scenario:

Report with various headers - headers name remain fixed but column number may differ - find missing/blank cells/data after applying various autofilter.
Finally, colour the missing/blank data/cells red which gets shared with users to complete.

Guidance required:
I have these two ways of selecting the data in auto filtered range to apply red colour. There are flaws in both ways if the autofilter doesn't return any result, it apply colours to all the cells in the column. Any Other ways of selecting the auto filtered range

1st way: Using DataRangebody

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_query__57")
.Range.AutoFilter Field:=a, Criteria1:=Array("Barclays", "HSBC", "Lloyds"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
.ListColumns(p).DataBodyRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

2nd way: Using column number down and go up

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_query__57")
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=a, Criteria1:=Array("Barclays", "HSBC", "Lloyds"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Range("Q4:Q" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: What are `a` and `p`? You are using column `A` for `xlUp` because it is guaranteed to always have a value and you're only trying to change the color of empty cells in column `Q`. Right?

Comment: a is a variable i set to look for column named Requestor in the table. As the report may not have constant column number every week. Equally p is a variable looking for Cost named column. So ideally if auto filter within these 2 column yeilds blank results then i would like to highlight the blank cells in column q red

Answer (score 0):

Try the next approach, please. It, basically, compares the number of filter rows against total rows for the column to be analyzed/processed:

```
Sub testFilteredOrNot()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, rngF As Range, lastRow As Long
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   
    '...............
    'do here the filtering...
    '...............
    
   Set rng = sh.Range("Q4:Q" & lastRow)
    Set rngF = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If rng.Rows.Count > rngF.Rows.Count Then
        rngF.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, change 'lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count)' with 'lastRow = sh.Range("Q" & Rows.Count'. I tested it on A:A column and I forgot adapting it...